# I want to create a method that will be available in all controllers, and views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, global, before-filter, view-helpers

i am making a ecommerce application in which the categories are visible in side bar on all pages. i wrote a method in application controller

```
def categories
  @categories = Category.all
end
```

but how can i make this method available to all controllers and actions by default so that i dont have to specifically call this method in every action

```
def list
  categories
  @products = Product.order('title').page(params[:page]).per(4)
end
```

Comment: define that method in application_controller and after application controller definition add `helper_method :categories` (what you want is called `helper_method`)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can define your method in `application_controller.rb` and since every other controller inherits from this one, that method will be available to all the controllers. Also, to make it a helper method for it to be available in the views, you can say `helper_method :my_method` in the `application_controller.rb`.

Now, for it to be automatically evaluated before any other action in a controller, you can use  a before_filter. Add `before_filter :my_method` 
in the controller you want this method to be evaluated before any action or in the **application_controller.rb**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the most proper way is to use gem cells. Definitely should try: http://cells.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score -1):

If you want something that has to be across the entire application, like in this case : **@categories** , then write a helper.

in `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def get_all_categories
     @categories = Category.all
  end
end
```

Answer (score -2):

I dont thing that there is a way to run this global. You could run it in a `before_filter` so its called before each action but you must specify this in every controller again!

My Suggestion would be to put the category sidebar stuff in a partial which contains a Call like this:

```
<% Category.all.each do |category| %>
     <% do stuff to display all categories %>
<% end %>
```

Then you could simply add the `render` call to your `layout/application.html.erb` that would do it for you!

Comment: `You could run it in a before_filter so its called before each action but you must specify this in every controller again` ... If you place a `before_filter` in the ApplicationController, you don't have to specify it again in every controller action (since by default they inherit the filters).  Also, you're doing model calls in the views which is never a good thing.  Go easy on throwing the f word around.

Comment: Its not a problem to do a `all` call in the view its okay to call Methods on the model a long as there is no logic in it which belongs to the `model` or the `controller`.

Comment: I think something like this definitely belongs in the view, possibly in a helper. I'd add <% cache('sidebar_categories') do %> around it and have an update to a sidebar category invalidate this.